# How can i call Angular component function using dynamic generated button using server side data table

Tags: jquery, angular, dynamic

I have loaded data from the server-side data table and in the last column, I have an edit button to load data in edit mode which is on the same page.

When I click on edit button, it is not calling Angular component function. Here i am adding code snippet

**Component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrandsModel } from '../models/index';

    import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
    declare var $: any;
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-brands',
        templateUrl: './brands.component.html'
    })

    export class BrandsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
        results: any;
        data: any;
        index = 0;
        actionMode: string;
        brand_id: string;
        brand_name: string;
        serviceUrl = environment.serviceUrl;
        constructor(private brands: BrandsModel) {
            this.actionMode = 'Add Brand';
            this.brand_id = '';
            this.brand_name = '';
        }

        init() {
            this.brand_id = '';
            this.actionMode = 'Add Brand';
        }

        getBrands() {
            const data = {
                'act': 'BKSTP005'
            };
            this.brands.getBrands(data).subscribe((res) => {
                this.results = res;
            });
        }

        addBrand(frmdata: any) {
            frmdata['act'] = 'BKSTP004';
            if (this.brand_id !== '') {
                this.updateBrand(frmdata);
                this.getBrands();
            } else {
                this.brands.addBrand(frmdata).subscribe((res) => this.data = res);
                this.getBrands();
            }
        }
        updateBrand(frmdata: any) {
            frmdata['act'] = 'BKSTP016';
            frmdata['brand_id'] = this.brand_id !== '' ? this.brand_id : '';
            this.brands.updateBrand(frmdata).subscribe((res) => this.data = res);
            setTimeout(function () {
                this.brand_id = '';
                this.actionMode = 'Add Brand';
                // $('.alert').hide();
            }, 500);
        }
        add() {
            this.brand_id = '';
            this.brand_name = '';
            this.actionMode = 'Add Brand';
        }
        getBrand(brand_id: any) {
            this.actionMode = 'Update Brand';
            this.brands.getBrandById({ act: 'BKSTP021', brand_id: brand_id }).subscribe((res) => {
                this.brand_id = res.data._id;
                this.brand_name = res.data.name;
                console.log(this.brand_name);
            });

        }

        handleClick(event) {
            console.log(event);
        }
        ngOnInit() {

        }
```

**Loading data into the table using server-side datatable**

```
        ngAfterViewInit() {
            const self = this;
            const serviceUrl = this.serviceUrl;
            $(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#example1').DataTable({
                        'paging': true,
                        'lengthChange': false,
                        'searching': false,
                        'ordering': true,
                        'info': true,
                        'autoWidth': false,
                        'ajax': {
                            url: serviceUrl,
                            type: 'post',
                            data: function (d) {
                                d.act = 'BKSTP005';
                            },
                            error: function (e) {
                                console.log(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }, 400);

                $('body').on('click', '.editbrand', function (){
                    const item = $(this).data('item');
                    self.getBrand(item);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

**Data loaded successfully. All is good so far**

**View**

```
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                Manage Brands
                <small></small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">Manage Brands</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="row">
```

**This section is for loading table**

```
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Brands</h3>
                            <small class="pull-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" (click)="add()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Brand</button>
                            </small>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Sl No</th>
                                        <th>Brand</th>
                                        <th class="pull-right">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**This section is for adding and updating brand**

```
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="box box-primary">
                        <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="data && data.status==1">
                            <strong>Success!</strong> {{data.message}}.
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-info" *ngIf="data && data.status==2">
                            <strong>Info!</strong> {{data.message}}.
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <h3 class="box-title">{{actionMode}}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <form novalidate #frm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addBrand(frm.value)" role="form">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="brand">Brand</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="brand" name="name" [(ngModel)]="brand_name" placeholder="Enter brand">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

**View After loading data can be seen in attached image**

[image: Image in add mode]

**It should look like below image after clicking on edit button**

[image]

But when i click on edit button, it will not update form fields. I am able to call component function using jquery but it is not updating view with heading "Update Brand" and not event updating ngForm.

Hopefully the shared code will help you all to understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question on StackOverflow shared by [Mark Rajcok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215945/mark-rajcok)

**Here is the answer**

```
    ApplicationRef.tick() - similar to AngularJS's $rootScope.$digest() -- i.e., check the full component tree
    NgZone.run(callback) - similar to $rootScope.$apply(callback) -- i.e., evaluate the callback function inside the Angular zone. I think, but I'm not sure, that this ends up checking the full component tree after executing the callback function.
    ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() - similar to $scope.$digest() -- i.e., check only this component and its children
    You can inject ApplicationRef, NgZone, or ChangeDetectorRef into your component.
```